# Creating a java file with docker image and creating a kubernetes cluster resulted in pod CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am trying to create a simple printsomething() from java and loading it onto docker container to create a k8s cluster for a proof of concept.

On docker, I am able to run the image (as shown below) however, when I created the cluster on k8s, I get the error CrashLoopBackOff. However, the log file seem to show the expected stdout from the image.
I am likely confuse on the approach here and the right way of executing it, can anyone please advise and guide? should this be expected?
Thanks very much in advance.

```
$ kubectl logs cimage-deployment-679d474cb7-fgj2c -p
printing from java
```

docker run as expected:

```
  $ docker run dockhub/cimage
    printing from java
    $ 

**//describe deployment:**  
    $ kubectl describe deployment cimage-deployment
Name:                   cimage-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Mon, 30 Aug 2021 11:24:45 +0800
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               deploy=cimage
Replicas:               3 desired | 3 updated | 3 total | 0 available | 3 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
Labels:  deploy=cimage
Containers:
cimage:
Image:        dockhub/cimage
Port:         <none>
Host Port:    <none>
Environment:  <none>
Mounts:       <none>
Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
          Type           Status  Reason
          ----           ------  ------
          Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
          Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
        OldReplicaSets:  <none>
        NewReplicaSet:   cimage-deployment-679d474cb7 (3/3 replicas created)
        Events:          <none>
```

**//describe pod**

```
    $ kubectl describe pod cimage
Name:         cimage-deployment-679d474cb7-fgj2c  
Namespace:    default  
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:   Mon, 30 Aug 2021 11:24:45 +0800
Labels:       deploy=cimage
pod-template-hash=679d474cb7  
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.5
IPs:
IP:           172.17.0.5
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/cimage-deployment-679d474cb7  
Containers:  
cimage:
Container ID:   docker://8891073c9e28c0b795c3c3b81f01d6c0fdd45785b102c458a28f58be3bfdbeed  
Image:          dockhub/cimage
Image ID:       docker-pullable://dockhub/cimage@sha256:fcbbb160653681a06bceac0f7144a472326adb53c7f2335a32d188a854340456  
Port:           <none>
Host Port:      <none>
State:          Waiting
Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
Reason:       Completed
Exit Code:    0
Started:      Mon, 30 Aug 2021 12:58:59 +0800
Finished:     Mon, 30 Aug 2021 12:58:59 +0800
Ready:          False
Restart Count:  23
Environment:    <none>
Mounts:
  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-vpjc8 (ro)
Conditions:
Type              Status
Initialized       True 
Ready             False
ContainersReady   False 
PodScheduled      True
Volumes:  
  kube-api-access-vpjc8:  
Type: Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)  
TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
Type     Reason   Age                    From               Message
----     ------   ----                   ----               -------
Warning  BackOff  3m15s (x435 over 98m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

adding get events

```
    $ kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                                    MESSAGE
59m         Normal    Pulling             pod/cimage-deployment-679d474cb7-fgj2c    Pulling image "dockhub/cimage"
4m34s       Warning   BackOff             pod/cimage-deployment-679d474cb7-fgj2c    Back-off restarting failed container
4m29s       Warning   BackOff             pod/cimage-deployment-679d474cb7-gbrfn    Back-off restarting failed container
4m31s       Warning   BackOff             pod/cimage-deployment-679d474cb7-vhwfx    Back-off restarting failed container
7m32s       Normal    Scheduled           pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Successfully assigned default/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc to minikube
5m57s       Normal    Pulling             pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Pulling image "dockhub/cimage"
7m27s       Normal    Pulled              pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Successfully pulled image "dockhub/cimage" in 3.779122485s
5m54s       Normal    Created             pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Created container cimage
7m23s       Normal    Pulled              pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Successfully pulled image "dockhub/cimage" in 3.116714272s
7m8s        Normal    Pulled              pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Successfully pulled image "dockhub/cimage" in 3.458218385s
2m29s       Warning   BackOff             pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Back-off restarting failed container
6m39s       Normal    Pulled              pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Successfully pulled image "dockhub/cimage" in 3.577472371s
5m54s       Normal    Pulled              pod/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc    Successfully pulled image "dockhub/cimage" in 3.41519015s
7m32s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff   Created pod: cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff-4wrjc
7m32s       Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/cimage-deployment              Scaled up replica set cimage-deployment-84dd6f49ff to 1
```

//follow up to the solution by Anisha, this occur,
Hey Ashish, I think my follow up question is unrelated to the original topic, but can I please check why this behavior occur? Would the pod not restart continuously? I cant see to find a param that says stop after "x" tries

```
$ kubectl get pod
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-2x9vr   1/1     Running   0          68s
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-vfpsm   1/1     Running   0          68s
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-wxdxf   1/1     Running   0          68s

$ kubectl get pod
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-2x9vr   1/1     Running   2          7m48s
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-vfpsm   1/1     Running   2          7m48s
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-wxdxf   1/1     Running   2          7m48s

$ kubectl get pod
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-2x9vr   1/1     Running   5          20m
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-vfpsm   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          20m
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-wxdxf   1/1     Running   5          20m


$ kubectl get pod
NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-2x9vr   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   31         4h19m
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-vfpsm   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   31         4h19m
jimage-deployment-5cd99c7bf4-wxdxf   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   33         4h19m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your main process a running application or something that executes and finishes? Especially since you say you are just trying to print some text. The main process in any container needs to be a running process, otherwise if the main process ends or exits then docker feels the container understands that as the application has failed and restarts it, hence it can go into a loop of restarting again and again.

You can may be use an application that is running on a port:

An example here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Could you suggest me some ways to perform the proof of concept as simplified as possible? Without the use of web/front end

Comment: Simplest thing I can say is add a sleep for some duration, like half hour then the application will print whatever you intend and will keep waiting and keep the program running for 30 minutes

Comment: Thanks Ashish! Clear and concise replies and suggestions. May I ask if you think a while(true) infinite loop will work? though that would seem to be a design flaw as it will be difficult to exit the loop without stdin.

Comment: Hey Anhish, i have edited the code to your proposed solution, however I believe there is a pre-defined setting for CrashLoopBackOff that I am not able to locate. Is this the only reason that the fault is still occurring albeit at a slower pace?

Comment: As I understand there is no setting, is the crashloopback still happening? if Yes then there may be a different problem, aside from the constant running app problem. Does your application print anything to stdout? you can check if you are getting any logs by using kubectl logs <pod-name>.

Comment: Yes I deduce it to be a logic issue, since it is sleeping and then printing it would inevidently fail and depending on the sequence and round robin, it might miss getting restarted. do you by any chance have any good resource material for k8s?

Comment: For resource regarding k8s I usually look at the kubernetes docs, you may refer to some common examples for java in docker/k8s, may be you can try this example:
https://www.oreilly.com/content/how-to-manage-docker-containers-in-kubernetes-with-java/

Comment: Thank you, yes I saw that. Is there any udemy courses that you would recommend? Are you on any group where we can chat more?

Comment: I had done a udemy course but i think that was for advanced devops course, so I would not recommend that.
No I am not part of any group, actually I am new here myself, if there any groups you recommend then I can join for chat

Comment: ah ok, i would not mind having a look at it, please do share if that is fine. oh ok, yes i am also in search of one myself..